# Visual Studio forces use System.Net.Http in Reference Assembly rather than the one specified in Nuget

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, .net-assembly

I reference System.Net.Http as a nuget package in my project, the references are correct in packages.config and .csproj file, but in Visual Studio property tab it always uses the package in system's Reference Assembly path, does anybody know why?

Another weird thing is this file in built `<webproj>\bin\roslyn` has another version, seems it doesn't use the dll file neither in nuget nor in Reference Assembly.

And actually the System.Net.Http.dll in nuget package, in Reference Assembly, in built `<webproj>\bin\roslyn` directory are have different versions, the file in `<webproj>\bin\roslyn` seems use the file of Visual Studio directory(C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\Extensions\aqwf5fqp.2lv\System.Net.Http.dll **or** C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\system.net.http\4.3.0\runtimes\win\lib\net46\System.Net.Http.dll **or** C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\system.net.http\4.3.0\lib\net46\System.Net.Http.dll, judged by its version and file size)

| dll in different path | assembly version |
| --- | --- |
| dll in nuget, package version 4.3.4 | 4.1.1.3 |
| dll in Reference Assembly(aka referenced in VS property tab) | 4.2.0.0 |
| dll in built `<webproj>\bin\roslyn` directory | 4.1.1.0 |

in packages.config
`<package id="System.Net.Http" version="4.3.4" targetFramework="net472" />`

in .csproj

```xml
    <Reference Include="System.Net.Http, Version=4.1.1.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\lib\Nugets\System.Net.Http.4.3.4\lib\net46\System.Net.Http.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
```

in property tab
[image]

And I want to **force VS(property tab) or the file in bin\roslyn to use the dll in nuget package**, how to do it please? Thank you.

Comment: Try this link and see if it works:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-restore-troubleshooting

Answer (score -1):

You can try [Migrate from packages.config to PackageReference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/migrate-packages-config-to-package-reference).

This can help you **Manage all project dependencies in one place**: Just like project to project references and assembly references, NuGet package references (using the PackageReference node) are managed directly within project files rather than using a separate packages.config file.